# Android SIP no incoming call event (doubango)

Tags: android, events, sip, phone-call

I've been trying to integrate Doubango Sip Stack.

First of all I've tried to go with the manual and test call example.

But I'm not recieving ACTION_INVITE event in my broadcast reciever, although I've added all filters etc. I get registration event without any issues.

At last I've checked out IMSDroid architecture and did the same - NativeService and Engine, extending ngn classes. Added service to manifest etc.

But i'm still not getting incoming call event, although I'm getting registration events.

What am I doing wrong here? And what is the approach?

p.s. my code looks pretty much like the one listed here at the bottom:
http://kehers.github.io/2014/06/04/sip-on-android.html (see doubango example)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the blog post referenced in your question. There could be a couple of reasons why you are not getting an incoming call event. Did you register a receiver for the incoming call?

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {  
  // Get engines
  mEngine = NgnEngine.getInstance();
  mSipService = mEngine.getSipService();

  // ...code blocks

  // Incoming call broadcast receiver
  final IntentFilter intentRFilter = new IntentFilter();
  callStateReceiver = new CallStateReceiver();
  intentRFilter.addAction(NgnInviteEventArgs.ACTION_INVITE_EVENT);
  registerReceiver(callStateReceiver, intentRFilter);
}
```

The receiver:

```
public class CallStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if(NgnInviteEventArgs.ACTION_INVITE_EVENT.equals(action)){
      NgnInviteEventArgs args = 
                intent.getParcelableExtra(NgnEventArgs.EXTRA_EMBEDDED);
      if(args == null){
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Invalid event args");
        return;
      }

      NgnAVSession avSession
                = NgnAVSession.getSession(args.getSessionId());
      if (avSession == null) {
        return;
      }

      final InviteState callState = avSession.getState();
      NgnEngine mEngine = NgnEngine.getInstance();

      switch(callState){
        case NONE:
        default:
        break;
        case INCOMING:
          Log.i("DEBUG", "Incoming call");
          // Ring
          mEngine.getSoundService().startRingTone();
          break;
        case INCALL:
          Log.i("DEBUG", "Call connected");
          mEngine.getSoundService().stopRingTone();
          break;
        case TERMINATED:
          Log.i("DEBUG", "Call terminated");
          mEngine.getSoundService().stopRingTone();
          mEngine.getSoundService().stopRingBackTone();
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Secondly, did you use correct SIP account details for the configuration? Ensure you replace *sip_username*, *sip_domain*, *sip_password*, *sip_server_port* and *sip_server_host* with valid details.

```
NgnEngine mEngine = NgnEngine.getInstance();
INgnConfigurationService mConfigurationService
            = mEngine.getConfigurationService();
mConfigurationService.putString(NgnConfigurationEntry.IDENTITY_IMPI,
                                    "sip_username");
mConfigurationService.putString(NgnConfigurationEntry.IDENTITY_IMPU, 
        String.format("sip:%s@%s", "sip_username", "sip_domain"));
mConfigurationService.putString(NgnConfigurationEntry.IDENTITY_PASSWORD,
                                    "sip_password");
mConfigurationService.putString(NgnConfigurationEntry.NETWORK_PCSCF_HOST, 
                                    "sip_server_host");
mConfigurationService.putInt(NgnConfigurationEntry.NETWORK_PCSCF_PORT, 
                                    "sip_server_port");
mConfigurationService.putString(NgnConfigurationEntry.NETWORK_REALM,
                                    "sip_domain");
mConfigurationService.commit();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It turned out that your activity, using doubango top level api's should have design like their ims droid example. After porting ims droid design to my app events happened to work. It's crazy, that there's nothing about this in manual.